# Does not Override method from it's superclass?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, configuration, javabeans

in public void `configureViewResolvers`, the Overriding is marks as red underline

```
public class SpringConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
 private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

       @Autowired
        public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
        @Bean
        public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            return templateResolver;
        }
        @Bean
        public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
            templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
            return templateEngine;
        }
       @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            registry.viewResolver(resolver);
        }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    }
}
```

Comment: And why shouldn't it, that method isn't part of the `WebApplicationInitializer` interface, so there is nothing to override.

Comment: If you want to ```configureViewResolvers``` you need to implement the ```WebMvcConfigurer``` interface.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is WebMvcConfigurer https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html